# Is it possible to import dynamic shared Objects/Libaries in Jython?

Tags: object, dynamic, jython, shared

is it possible to import dynamic shared objects like "example.so" to import in jython?
In python these objects can be imported like any other module.

regards

Answer (score 0):

No. Jython can only use Java modules, not C-based ones.